# What is the RESTful and Rails way to add these actions to my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am adding tagging functionality to my app, via [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/).

That gem doesn't add controllers, but I would like to. I am adding the tagging functionality to my `Node` model.

On my `NodeController`, I know I could simply add the explicit actions like this:

```
  def add_tagged_user

  end

  def remove_tagged_user

  end

  def tagged_users

  end
```

But that doesn't feel very restful or Railsy.

The corresponding route would look like this:

```
resources :nodes do
   match :add_tagged_user, via: [:post], on: :member
   match :remove_tagged_user, via: [:delete], on: :member
   match :tagged_users, via: [:get], on: :member
end
```

Is there a RESTful or a more Railsy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a single TagsController, with routes that match the RESTful resource(s).

Something like

**Routes**

```
# routes.rb
resources :nodes do
  resources :tags, only: [:show, :create, :update]
end
resources :other_resources do
  resources :tags, only: [:show, :create, :update]
end
```

**Controller**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_taggable

  def create
    @taggable.tags.create(tag_params)
  end

  private

  def load_taggable
    # switches on params
    @taggable = if params[:node_id]
      Node.find(params[:node_id]
    elsif # other things that are taggable
      # OtherThing.find(...)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This feels confusing to me. I was hoping for something simpler.